# Conditionally manage intlTelInput dial-code in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, intl-tel-input

I am using intlTelInput. It's working . I want to manage dial-code based on radio input value. My primary mobile input section

```
<input type="test" class="phone_number">

  $(".phone_number").intlTelInput({
    hiddenInput: [],
    placeholderNumberType: "MOBILE",
    separateDialCode: true,
  });
```

It's working properly . But when I try to fix dial-code based on condition it's not working. Still can be available all value in dropdown

```
<input type="radio" class="phone" name="phone" value="YES"> Yes
<input type="radio" class="phone" name="phone" value="NO"> No

$(".phone").on('click', function () {
let has_phone = $("input[name='phone']:checked").val();
if(has_phone == 'YES') {
    $(".phone_number").intlTelInput({
        hiddenInput: [],
        onlyCountries: ["uk"],
        initialCountry: "UK",
        placeholderNumberType: "MOBILE",
        separateDialCode: true,
    });            
}else {
    $(".phone_number").intlTelInput({
        hiddenInput: [],
        placeholderNumberType: "MOBILE",
        separateDialCode: true,
    });              
}
});
```